# Split string in characters and merge with formatting

Tags: strings

How can I create a macro

```
\split{ABC}
```

that outputs

[image]

where the formatting of the characters are made with another macro, i.e.

```
\formatchar{A}
```

where

```
\def\formatchar#1{{\color{red}#1}}
```

for any string length?

I tried to modify the code in
[Split a character string n by n](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171007/split-a-character-string-n-by-n)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\def\split#1#2{%
    \StrSplit{#2}{1}\tempa\tempb
    x%
    \tempa\let\tempa\empty
    \unless\ifx\tempb\empty\def\tempa{|\split{1}\tempb}\fi
    y%
    \tempa
}

\begin{document}
\split{1}{ABCD}
\end{document}
```

And I get x and y before and after (since I failed limiting with a command and }) but I cannot get it to format properly. Also I would like to avoid the {1} in call, and use

```
\split{ABCD}
```

only. It is always 1-charater splits.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your input is not guaranteed to be “ASCII-only” an approach with `\seq_set_split:Nnn` may not work.

I changed the name to `\splitchars` because `\split` is taken up by `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand{\formatchar}{m}{%
  \textcolor{red!90!yellow}{#1}% <--- or whatever you like
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\splitchars}{O{|}m}
 {% #1 = optional separator, default |
  % #2 = text to split
  \mflxvii_split:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__mflxvii_split_items_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mflxvii_split:nn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__mflxvii_split_items_seq
  \text_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__mflxvii_split_items_seq { \formatchar{##1} }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__mflxvii_split_items_seq { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\splitchars{ABC}

\splitchars[--]{ABC}

\splitchars{ábç}

\splitchars{ÅÄÖ}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to get a list-like output, here's an extension that allows a different separator between the last two items.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand{\formatchar}{m}{%
  \textcolor{red!90!yellow}{#1}% <--- or whatever you like
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\splitchars}{O{|}O{#1}m}
 {% #1 = optional separator, default |
  % #2 = optional separator between last two
  % #3 = text to split
  \mflxvii_split:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__mflxvii_split_items_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mflxvii_split:nnn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__mflxvii_split_items_seq
  \text_map_inline:nn { #3 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__mflxvii_split_items_seq { \formatchar{##1} }
   }
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l__mflxvii_split_items_seq { #2 } { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\splitchars{ABC}

\splitchars[--]{ABC}

\splitchars{ábç}

\splitchars{ÅÄÖ}

\splitchars[, ][ and ]{ÅÄÖ}

\splitchars[, ][ and ]{ÅÄ}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there some way to get in contact with you for a commission? I have not found any 'dm'/'pm' function on this site.

Comment: It did not work, and gives error LaTeX cmd Error: Command '\split' already defined. I'm running pdfLaTeX, TeXLive 2022

Comment: In addition it cannot handle ÅÄÖ. Can this be corrected?

Comment: @mf67 I changed the name, because `\split` is preempted by `amsmath`. But you see that it deals correctly with `ÅÄÖ`. Are you using UTF-8? I tried with TeX Live 2022 and it works the same.

Comment: I don't understand. I take your sample, paste into a new TexLive 2022 PdfLatex document at Overleaf and get Undefined control sequence.: \mflxvii_split:nn ...tems_seq \text_map_inline:nn 
                                                  {#2}{\seq_put_right:Nn \l_...
l.33 \splitchars{ABC} (it does not help that his comment box is too small to display it well.)

Comment: After some investigation, Overleaf must run in TexLive 2023 mode to accept the code.

Comment: Would it be possible to expand the optional arguments so that a “last separator” is specified too? E.g. `\splitchars[, ][and]{ABCDE}`gives “A, B, C, D and E”?

Comment: @mf67 Sure. Added in the last edit.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution, which makes use of Lua's `gsub` and `sub` built-in functions. Actually, the code uses versions of the `gsub` and `sub` functions that can handle utf8-encoded characters directly.

The main user-level macro is called `\splitstring` rather than `\split`, because the [amsmath](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package defines an environment called `split` along with macros called `\split` and `\endsplit`.

Observe that (a) the argument of `\splitstring` can contain whitespace and (b) `formatchar` is implemented as a Lua function rather than as a LaTeX macro.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}  % for '\textcolor' macro

% Lua-side code
\directlua{
```

```lua
  function formatchar ( c )
     return ( '\\textcolor{red}{\\textbf{' .. c .. '}}|' )
  end
  function split ( s )
     s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , '.' , formatchar )
     return ( unicode.utf8.sub ( s , 1 , -2 ) ) % delete final '|'
  end
```

```tex
}
% LaTeX-side code
\newcommand\splitstring[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(split('#1'))}}

\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this example
\splitstring{ABC}
\splitstring{123abc}
\splitstring{Hello World}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I never learnt Lua but understand it is very powerful. Can you recommend a good starter book for Lua with LaTeX?

Comment: @mf67 - I will assume you're pretty good at LaTeX. I'm not sure there are a great many books out there that would fit your stated need. I'd recommend studying  [An Introduction to LuaTeX (Part 1): What is it—and what makes it so different?](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/An_Introduction_to_LuaTeX_(Part_1)%3A_What_is_it%E2%80%94and_what_makes_it_so_different%3F) and [An Introduction to LuaTeX (Part 2): Understanding \directlua](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/An_Introduction_to_LuaTeX_(Part_2)%3A_Understanding_%5Cdirectlua). There are lots of books on learning Lua.

Comment: No, I'm not very good at all. I try to understand, but mostly copy and try to adjust what others have done earlier to fit my needs. I'm not very successful most of the time… Thank you for the links.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution attempt using ExplSyntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__my_split_seq
\NewDocumentCommand { \split } { m } {  \__my_split:n { #1 }  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__my_split:n #1
{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__my_split_seq {} { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__my_split_seq \l__my_split_seq
  {  \__my_split_fn:n { ##1 }  }
  % \seq_log:N \l__my_split_seq
  \seq_use:Nn \l__my_split_seq { | }
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__my_split_fn:n #1 {   {  \color { red } #1  }   }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\split{ABCD}

\split{1234}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, very kind of you. I don't know Expl, but it seems good. Why is one line commented? Is it important?

Answer (score 4):

Nobody actually tried to use the OPs code with `xstring`, which is arguably the easiest :) Here a recursive definition of `\split`, using `\StrSplit` and `\IfStrEq`. It works also for accented letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\formatchar#1{{\color{red}#1}}

\def\split#1{%
    \StrSplit{#1}{1}{\tempa}{\tempb}% split into first character \tempa and the rest \tempb
    \formatchar{\tempa}%            % print first character in red
    \IfStrEq{\tempb}{}{}{%          % if rest is empty (first {}) do nothing (second {}), which will stop the recursive loop.
    |%                              % else: print a bar, and
    \split{\tempb}%                 % call the function again for the rest,
    }%                              % which will split the first character of the rest etc.
}

\begin{document}
\split{ABCDÅÄÖ}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice idea: +1 . // The stop condition is critical to avoid infinite loops. It's in your code, off course, if you know what to look for. Do you have any hints for future readers on this subject? Or can you augment your code with some comments? Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO I added comments, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Thank you: great

Answer (score 3):

Since there are no LaTeX2e solutions offered, I give one here.  I use a token cycle to grab characters one-by-one from the argument.  This solution assumes the argument has no macros and no groups.  I omitted those, because no guidance was given on how they should be handled, though they can be handled, as needed.

If unicode characters need to be handled, compilation must be performed under xelatex or lualatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle,xcolor}
\newcommand\formatchar[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\def\split#1{%
  \tokencycle{\formatchar{##1}\splitchar}
  {}{}{##1\splitchar}#1\endtokencycle}
\newcommand\splitchar{\tcpeek\z\ifx\empty\z\else$\mid$\fi}
\begin{document}
\split{ABCD}

\split{Å ÄÖ}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I don't think that `$\mid$` is quite right, though. I'd suggest either `|` or `\textbar`.

Comment: @Mico Maybe so, semantically; however, there appears to be no visual distinction between `$\mid$` and `\textbar`.