expand argument before using it
how to make \eqdef work when passed an argument ?
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\s@plit<#1#2>{%
  \ifx\empty#2%
    #1%
  \else
    #1\s@plit<#2>%
  \fi}

\def\Split#1#2{\s@plit<#2\empty>}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Split{1}{aa=  11, bb= 2} % strip white space

\def\eqdef#1{\eqdefA#1,,}
\def\eqdefA#1,{\ifx^#1^\else \eqdefB#1,\expandafter\eqdefA\fi}
\def\eqdefB#1=#2,{\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{#2}}

\eqdef{aa=11,bb=2} % no problem

\aa

\bb

\eqdef{\expandafter\Split{1}{aa=  11, bb= 2}} % need to expand argument correctly.



\end{document}


I guess you have no idea of what \expandafter does, do you?

Yes I do . could you use it to solve this problem ?

What are you trying to achieve (in words)?

\expandafter\Split{ expands { but that is not expandable

What is the purpose of the first argument of \Split? \Split neither uses nor returns it. It is just gobbled.

@UlrichDiez  I found \Split from this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171007/split-a-character-string-n-by-n    I also want to know the role of that argument .

@XCN Seeems that post is about splitting a string into sub-strings where each sub-string except the first sub-string is to consst of an amount of characters that is to be specified by \Split's 1st argument. Seems in that example it doesn't have a rôle other than illustrating what syntax the questioner wishes the macro \Split to have.

@Mico the code aims to define each equality in a list with \def command regardless of spaces  in it.

If you want to zap spaces inside the argument, and if you know all you'll be left with are unexpandable tokens, you can do something like
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\eqdef#1{\expandafter\eqdefA\expanded{\zap@space#1 \@empty},,}
\def\eqdefA#1,{\ifx^#1^\else \eqdefB#1,\expandafter\eqdefA\fi}
\def\eqdefB#1=#2,{\@namedef{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\eqdef{aa=11,bb=2} % no problem

\aa

\bb

\eqdef{aa=  33, bb= 4}

\aa

\bb

\end{document}


You're approaching the problem from a wrong point of view.
Since your aim is to define commands, you don't need expandability and how to do it has already been presented.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\eqdef}{m}
 {% #1 = comma separated assignments <var>=<value>
  % <var> should be undefined
  \xcn_eqdef:n {#1}
 }
\keys_define:nn { xcn/eqdef }
 {
  unknown .code:n = \cs_new:cpn { \l_keys_key_str } {#1},
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_eqdef:n
 {
  \keys_set:nn { xcn/eqdef } {#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\eqdef{first=11,second=2}

\eqdef{third   = 4,  fourth = 8}

\first, \second, \third, \fourth

{\ttfamily
|\meaning\first|\par
|\meaning\second|\par
|\meaning\third|\par
|\meaning\fourth|\par
}

\end{document}

You can see that no space has crept in.

Alternatively, with exactly the same output,
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\eqdef}{m}
 {% #1 = comma separated assignments <var>=<value>
  % <var> should be undefined
  \xcn_eqdef:n {#1}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_eqdef:n
 {
  \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_tmpa_prop {#1}
  \prop_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_prop
   {
    \cs_new:cpn {##1} {##2}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\eqdef{first=11,second=2}

\eqdef{third   = 4,  fourth = 8}

\first, \second, \third, \fourth

{\ttfamily
|\meaning\first|\par
|\meaning\second|\par
|\meaning\third|\par
|\meaning\fourth|\par
}


\end{document}


is it possible to suffix integer behind name first ?  That is to say, make \eqdef like this:  \eqdef{first11 = 4,   first12 =  8}

@XCN No, of course, if you think to use \first1.

Maybe, you want remove space before \eqdefA is executed. The macro \stripspaces can be created for this purpose:
\def\eqdef#1{\expandafter\eqdefA\expanded{\stripspaces#1 {\end} },,}
\def\eqdefA#1,{\ifx^#1^\else \eqdefB#1,\expandafter\eqdefA\fi}
\def\eqdefB#1=#2,{\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{#2}}

\def\stripspaces #1 {\ifx\end#1\empty\else #1\expandafter\stripspaces\fi}

\eqdef{aa=11,bb=2} % no problem

\aa

\bb

\eqdef{ aa = 13 , bb = 15 }

\aa

\bb

\bye

The \eqdef and the concept of usage the value of aa by \aa is only for experimental purpose. I warn you to use it in general. When you use (for example) \eqdef{fi=13} then you define \fi as a macro with value 13 and LaTeX crashes (because it uses TeX primitive \fi in its internal macros).
